# Get Row data in text field when we click on row in apex:pageBlockTable

Tags: visualforce

When i click on any row using onrowclick function in apex:pageBlockTable. I am able to select the row using javascript functionality but i am not able to get the selected row data to row data in alert box.

Can any one help me How to get selected row data in controller?

Please find the vfpage and controller

```
<apex:page controller="petwizardcontroller" sidebar="false">
<apex:form title="">
    Household Name: <apex:inputText value="{!ID_c}" />
    <apex:commandButton value="Search" action="{!doSearch}"/>

<apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageblockTable value="{!lstQuery}" var="eachRecord">        
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Household__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord['Name']}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Phone__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.of_Childrens__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.of_Exiting_Pets__c}"/>
        <apex:column value="{!eachRecord.Address__c}"/>
        <apex:selectList value="{!eachRecord.Phone__c}">
        <apex:selectOptions value="{!eachRecord.of_Childrens__c}">
            </apex:selectOptions>
        </apex:selectList>
    </apex:pageblockTable>
    <apex:commandButton value="None of These" reRender="PCSHouseTable"/>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Controller

```
public class petwizardcontroller {
public string ID_c{get;set;}
public List<PCS_Household__c> lstQuery{get;set;}

public petwizardcontroller(){
    lstQuery=new List<PCS_Household__c>();
}

public Void doSearch(){

    string Query='';
    Query='SELECT Name,Household__c,Phone__c,of_Childrens__c,of_Exiting_Pets__c,Address__c FROM PCS_Household__c where Household__c LIKE \'%'+ID_c+'%\'';
    system.debug('==Query=='+Query);

    lstQuery=Database.query(Query);
    system.debug('==lstQuery=='+lstQuery);

}


}
```

Comment: You missed your code?

Comment: updated my code.

Comment: but how to get the row selected value in text fields thank you.

Answer (score 1):

By passing `this` to the JavaScript, the JavaScript has a reference to the DOM element that was clicked on:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" recordSetVar="cs">
<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlockTable onRowClick="handler(this);" value="{!cs}" var="c">
    <apex:column value="{!c.Name}"/>
    <apex:column value="{!c.Birthdate}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlock>
<script>
function handler(tr) {
    alert(tr.tagName);
}
</script>
</apex:page>
```

and can then use raw DOM processing or jQuery to generate the required output or other logic.

The above answer is to the original question which did not include the part about passing the data to the controller. A way to do that is to call the JavaScript generated by an [apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) from the handler which in turn calls a controller method passing say the ID of the clicked row.